# Assigning a range to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, range

I know that assigning some values to an array would be as below:

```
arrayX = [20080711, 20080712, 20080713, 20080714]
```

But I couldn't find out how to quickly assign these values as a range to the array.

Comment: The "array" is called `list` in Python.

Comment: `arrayX = []`.

`for i in range(20080711, 20080714):
   arrayX.append(i)`

This will result `[20080711, 20080712, 20080713, 20080714]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.x:

```
arrayX = range(20080711, 20080714+1)
```

in Python 3.x:

```
arrayX = list(range(20080711, 20080714+1))
```

However, if your ints represent something like a date (YYYYMMDD), it will be trickier:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
arrayX = []
dt = datetime(2008, 7, 11)
while dt <= datetime(2008, 7, 14):
    arrayX.append(int(dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
    dt += timedelta(days=1)
```

which works over months and years.

Comment: Keen observation, Eumiro! Does the date code you wrote above count for leap years?